# How can I remove the blank space in urldate (while using ngerman and biblatex)?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, date, url

I want the urldate like the other dates. `\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}` seems not obviously be of help. Perhaps someone has an idea
Here is an MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
    
    \begin{document}
    
   My Birthday: 01.01.1900    
   
    \autocite{ctan}

\printbibliography    
    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the spaces by removing the `\thinspace`s from the relevant localisation macro `\mkbibdateshort`. Its original definition can be found in [`german.lbx` (ll. 28-41) in v3.16](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/german.lbx#L28-L41)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyExtras{german}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkdayzeros{\thefield{#3}}\adddot}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkmonthzeros{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}
         {}
         {\iffieldundef{#3}{/}{\adddot}}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
    
\begin{document}
  My Birthday: 01.01.1900

  \autocite{ctan}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (besucht am 01.10.2006)]

See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/891

Comment: thank you very much!